# Bluetooth thermal Printer Integration with React Native App

Tags: react-native

I want to integrate my react native application with **Bluetooth Thermal Printer**. Could anyone suggest which package is suitable for which type of model of **Bluetooth Thermal Printer**.

Answer (score 1):

[react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer](https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer). Best Bluetooth Thermal Printer Package I have used so far.

Hope this works for you too.